# Intel G630 Processor suitability

Tags: installation

I have a computer with an Intel 630 Processor, 4Gig Ram and 500 GB Hard Drive. Would this machine be able to run Ubuntu alongside Windows 8?  I am also thinking of starting an internet café initially with 10 computers.  Would I have to buy the Ubuntu CD for each machine or would one CD suffice?

Answer (score 0):

The computer is very good to run Ubuntu. 
And no, you don't need to buy more CD's. one is enought. Ubuntu is open source.